# iMac 27 (Late 2013) with two Thunderbolt displays

Tags: imac, thunderbolt

The iMac 27" late 2013 (Haswell processor) has 2 IO Thunderbolt ports. Is it possible to run two 2560x1440 displays at full resolution (Thunderbolt or via Dual DVI adapter) on the side of it's main display?

*As far as I know, the previous iMac could handle them with no problems and MacBook Pro Retina can handle them as well.*

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** its is possible. You can daisy chain (connect) two thunderbolt displays. 
See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219#18